# Cramér-Rao Lower Bound & Fisher information - error in textbook?

Tags: expected-value, notation, fisher-information

I'm currently reading the textbook "Statistics for Mathematician" from Victor Panaretos. On page 65, the author presents the following equation for the Cramér-Rao Lower Bound (Note: I set the numerator to 1 by assuming an unbiased estimator)

$$\text{Var}(T) \geq \frac{1}{n\int_{\mathcal{X}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\text{log }f(x;\theta))²\:f(x;\theta)dx}=\frac{1}{n\mathbb{E}[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\text{log }f(x;\theta) ]^2}$$

However, I don't understand the equality in the denominator, namely why $$\int_{\mathcal{X}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\text{log }f(x;\theta))²\:f(x;\theta)dx = \mathbb{E}[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\text{log }f(x;\theta) ]^2$$ holds.

Shouldn't it rather be $\int_{\mathcal{X}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\text{log }f(x;\theta))²\:f(x;\theta)dx = \mathbb{E}[(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\text{log }f(x;\theta))^2]$?

Comment: It appears that your integral for the expectation of the square of the score function in the second-last sentence is equivalent to the integral given in the last sentence. Equivalently, the denominator of the Cramer-Rao lower bound can be written in terms of the negative expectation of the second partial derivative of the score function.

Comment: It's the same thing really. You are saying $E[X^2]$ and they are saying $E[X]^2$.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips Thanks for the quick reply. The two integrals are indeed the same, but the expected values are not. In the second-last sentence I wrote $\mathbb{E}[X]²$, in the last sentence I wrote $\mathbb{E}[X²]$. I don't understand why the the two expected values should be the same in this case.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Why is it the same in this case, though? In general, $\mathbb{E}[X²] \neq \mathbb{E}[X]²$. For example, let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X²] = 1$, but $\mathbb{E}[X]²=0$.

Comment: I meant $E[X]^2$ is supposed to mean $E[X^2]$ and not $(E[X])^2$, as is quite clear from the context.  Putting a parenthesis as you have done certainly removes any ambiguity.

Comment: @StubbornAtom since that appears to have resolved the question you might post it as an answer.

Comment: I would ask OP @DrosoNeuro to post their own answer and accept it. Regarding notation, it is more standard to write the square of expectation as $(E[X])^2$ (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220452/is-it-okay-to-write-the-square-of-expectation-of-a-random-variable-x-as-math) for a related question).

Comment: Of course, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be simply a notation issue (thanks to @StubbornAtom for pointing this out): The author of the textbook probably used $\mathbb{E}[X]²$ to indicate $\mathbb{E}[X²]$. But $\mathbb{E}[X]²$ could also be understood as $(\mathbb{E}[X])²$, hence my confusion.